# Where were the dragon skulls?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Related to comments on [Where did Qyburn suggest that Cersei go?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100709/where-did-qyburn-suggest-that-cersei-go)

In Game of Thrones S08E05, towards the end we see Cersei & Jaime in a cellar we have seen previously in the show, with the various-sized skulls of dragons.
Arya chased a cat in there, Varys was conniving there, I have a vague but indistinct memory Joffrey may have even taken Sansa there...

But where was it? What building/castle/keep is it under?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But where was it? What building/castle/keep is it under?

Jamie and Cersei were in the cellars **below the Red Keep**. This is indeed the same location where Qyburn showed off the scorpion weapon to Cersei by shooting the skull of Balerion (season 7), and where Arya chased the cat to and overheard Varys conspiring with Illyrio Mopatis.

> ... with the various-sized skulls of dragons.

Originally the dragon skulls were in the Great Hall but Robert Baratheon had them moved to the cellars.

Comment: I think the specific secret passage that Jamie uses might also have been used various times before in the show.

Comment: I did wonder whether they'd made it to Maegor's Holdfast, though the geography was perhaps never entirely laid out for us to examine; I think all we know is one is inside the other.

Comment: I believe it's the same spot where Bronn was training Jaime and where Tyrion met with Jaime last season.

Answer (score 2):

It is stored in a Dank cellar in the Red Keep

Linked

> https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Skulls_of_the_Targaryen_dragons

Answer (score 0):

It leads down to the beach, as Tyrian told Jaime (S0805) when he set him free,

> "Keep following the stairs down as far as they will go... there will be a dinghy waiting for you"

Unfortuneately (for them), the rubble blocks all of the exits. Although I'm not sure why they didn't go back the way they came, it was probably also filled with rubble as the building collapsed around them.

Incidentally, this is how Arya found herself outside the walls of Kings Landing when she started chasing that cat in Season 1. She kept going down and down further yet until she spilled out onto the beach.